# Facing Same Issue again in the same project upgrade with jetty9 and apache CXF 3.1.4

Tags: spring, java-8, jetty, cxf

Hi I am facing same issue into the different module of same project where I have faced this issue with jetty9 and CXF 3.1.4

Error stack trace:

```
[LB][2015-12-15 15:31:39,497] o.s.t.c.TestContextManager               ERROR [main] Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@121f0ffd] to prepare test instance [com.flintenergy.fief.qv21.util.TripConversionUtilTest@2b2a0546]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) ~[spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300) [junit-4.10.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124) [surefire-junit4-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.17.jar:2.17]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdeRs': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/nio/SelectChannelConnector
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

My dependencies intros modules:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ fief-qv21 ---
[INFO] com.flintenergy.fief:fief-qv21:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.mdw360:mdw360-spring:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief.jde:fief-extension-jde:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief.jde:fief-jde-svcs-bus:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.mdw360:mdw360-core:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:13.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief.jde:fief-jde-svcs-db:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- com.flintenergy.fief:fief-specs:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- com.flintenergy.fief:fief-resources:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:3.1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:jar:3.0.0-milestone1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.7:test
[INFO] |  |  +- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.oauth.core:oauth-provider:jar:20100527:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.oauth.core:oauth:jar:20100527:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.7.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.0.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wss10:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wsu10:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wss11:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings-wssc:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:tests:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.0-beta:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:1.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.as400:jt400:jar:7.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.beanio:beanio:jar:2.0.3:test
[INFO] +- com.mdw360:mdw360-camel-test:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- com.mdw360:mdw360-camel-core:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.16:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-xstream:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.6:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-http:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-servlet:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:test
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-camel:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.3.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-test:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.15.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief.fca:fief-extension-fca:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle:ons:jar:10.2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.pojomatic:pojomatic:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.11.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.1.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.11.v20150529:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.mdw360:mdw360-test:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- com.mdw360.jde:jde-ext-client:jar:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.mdw360.jde:jde-ext-server:jar:classes:2.0.10-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- me.moocar:logback-gelf:jar:0.9.6p2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.cwbase:logback-redis-appender:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:ApplicationAPIs_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:ApplicationLogic_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:Base_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:BizLogicContainer_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:BizLogicContainerClient_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:castor:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:Connector:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:EventProcessor_EJB:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:EventProcessor_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:JdbjBase_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:ManagementAgent_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:commons-httpclient:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:jmxremote:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:jmxremote_optional:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:jmxri:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:Metadata:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:MetadataInterface:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:JdbjInterfaces_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:JdeNet_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:jt400:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:PMApi_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:Spec_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:System_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:SystemInterfaces_JAR:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.jde:log4j:jar:8.98.3:test
[INFO] |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] +- com.flintenergy.fief:fief-test-resources:jar:16.02.RC1-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  \- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.160:test
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.mock-javamail:mock-javamail:jar:1.9:test
[INFO] |  \- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:test
[INFO] |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:jar:2.0M10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.easytesting:fest-util:jar:1.2.5:test
[INFO] +- org.easytesting:fest-guava-assert:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-junit-adaptor:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-java-aspects:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |     \- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-java-adaptor-api:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |        +- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-java-annotations:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-model:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |        |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |        |     \- ru.yandex.qatools.properties:properties-loader:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |        |        \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] \- com.github.detro.ghostdriver:phantomjsdriver:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.json:json:jar:20080701:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- net.java.dev.jna:platform:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-android-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.18:compile
[INFO]    |  |     +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |     |  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-websocket:jar:8.1.9.v20130131:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-iphone-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.webbitserver:webbit:jar:0.4.14:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    \- org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:jar:2.33.0:compile
[INFO]       +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO]       +- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.48:compile
[INFO]       +- mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.9:compile
[INFO]       +- org.seleniumhq.selenium:jetty-repacked:jar:7.6.1:compile
[INFO]       +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]       \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.8:compile
```

My pom.xml depencies related jetty and cxf:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Please help me to find solution for this repeating issue. I know its dependency conflicts but I am not sure where its happening in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mix of CXF:

```
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:3.1.4:test
org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle:jar:3.0.0-milestone1:test
```

which is likely not a good idea.